# Недостаточно привилегий для создания синонима (synonym)

Tags: sql, oracle

Для подключения использую `PL/SQL Developer`.

Я захожу в под пользователем `user1` на базу `test`.
При попытке создания синонима получаю ошибку:

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges Create the synonym create or replace synonym example1 for user1.example1_1

Каких привилегий не достаточно и как их получить?

У меня есть `Object privileges(sys.data_pump_dir2): Execute, Read, Write (+, +, +), Role privileges` (нет никаких).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не хватает прав для создания синонима. Попросите администратора вашей БД дать вам нужную привилегию. Например так:
`GRANT CREATE SYNONYM TO user1`

Answer (score 1):

У тебя нет прав на создание синонима. Либо под `sys` заходи, либо расширяй свои `GRANT`